# Partially filter table if it meets certain conditions using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, tidyverse

I am using dplyr to try and partially filter a data frame, but only if a variable meets a certain condition. Here is a sample code of the data frame I am trying to filter:

```
tbl <- tribble(
  ~account, ~date, ~id, ~report_start, ~report_end,
  "a", as.Date('2022-09-03'), NA, NA, NA,
  "b", as.Date('2022-09-03'), NA, NA, NA,
  "c", as.Date('2022-09-03'), NA, NA, NA,
  "c", as.Date('2022-09-03'), NA, NA, NA,
  "e", as.Date('2022-09-03'), 1, as.Date('2022-07-04'), as.Date('2022-10-02'),
  "e", as.Date('2022-09-03'), 1, as.Date('2022-10-03'), as.Date('2022-12-15'),
  "e", as.Date('2022-09-03'), 2, as.Date('2022-03-28'), as.Date('2022-07-03'),
  "f", as.Date('2022-09-03'), NA, NA, NA,
  "g", as.Date('2022-09-03'), 2, as.Date('2022-07-04'), as.Date('2022-10-02'),
  "g", as.Date('2022-09-03'), 3, as.Date('2022-07-04'), as.Date('2022-12-15'),
)
```

and this is what the sample table looks like:

[image]

What I am trying to do is filter the table so that any rows where `id` is `NA` then I would like to keep them unchanged. But for rows where `id` is not `NA`, I would like to filter the table and only keep the rows where `date` >= `report_start` and <= `report_end`.

Ideally the table will filter down to look like this, where accounts that are `NA` for `id` remain untouched in the table, while only filtering the accounts where there was an `id` number for `date` between `report_start` and `report_end`:

[image]

I've tried using the following code to try and filter the table, but i end up filtering out all my rows where `id` is `NA`:

```
df <- tbl %>%
  filter(!is.na(id), (date >= report_start & date <= report_end))
```

I've tried other dplyr methods but cant seem to get it to work so any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt was close and had the right idea, but using a comma in `filter` is the equivalent of an "AND" clause which I don't think gave you all of what you needed. You also want to specify the rows of NAs that you want to keep using `|`. Try this instead

```r
tbl %>%
  filter(is.na(id) | (date >= report_start & date <= report_end))
```